# Swift: upload multiple images to Firestore and assign URLs to object

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uiimage

I'm making an app whereby users post 2 images. I'm using Firebase for storage and as my database.

In my method to upload the images what I had wanted to do was to essentially use this method to return the URLs separately as well. I had written the following:

```
 private func uploadImage(image: UIImage) -> URL? {
    let randomName = UUID()
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("\(randomName)/png")
    guard let uploadData = image.pngData() else { return nil}
    
    var imageUrl: URL?
    
    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                imageUrl = url
            }
        }
    }
    return imageUrl
}
```

And then I wrote the following 'post' method which is run when the submit button is tapped:

```
  @objc func post() {
        
        if let question = questionText.text,
            let hashtagText = hashtagTextField.text,
            let userHandle = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email,
            let firstImage = left.image,
            let secondImage = right.image,
            let firstImageURL = uploadImage(image: firstImage)?.absoluteString,
            let secondImageURL = uploadImage(image: secondImage)?.absoluteString
        {
            
            db.collection("posts").addDocument(data: [
                "firstImage" : firstImageURL,
                "secondImage" : secondImageURL,
                "question" : question,
                "hashtagText" : hashtagText,
                "userHandle" : userHandle
            ]) { (error) in
                if let e = error {
                    print("There was an issue saving data to Firestore, \(e)")
                } else {
                    print("Successfully saved data")
                    
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, obviously the first method is not going to work as the closure is run after imageUrl is returned, therefore returning nil.

I've been trying to figure out how to manage this scenario - I had considered using a loop to populate an array of images but this got messy and I'm sure it is not the standard way to handle this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `return imageUrl` is in the wrong place. It will return *before* Firebase has had time to store the image and return the url.

Additionally, the name of the file is not going to work. You currently have

```
storage.reference().child("\(randomName)/png")  //  xxxxx/png?
```

when it should be

```
storage.reference().child("\(randomName).png")  //  xxxxx.png
```

You can't 'return' data from a Firebase closure because firebase is asynchronous - a *completion handler* may possibly be a solution, but we don't know what the total use case is.

Let's assume you want want to store a users vacation picture in storage and then store that url in Firestore

```
 private func uploadImage(image: UIImage) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return } //this users uid
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child(uid).child("vacation.png")
       //the path will be storage/users uid/vacation.png
    guard let uploadData = image.pngData() else { return nil}

    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if url != nil {
                   //it's here where we store the imageUrl in Firestore
                   let dict = ["theUrl": url?.absoluteURL)]
                   let userRef = self.db.collection("users").document(uid)
                       //self.db points to *my* Firestore
                   userRef.collection("my_pics").addDocument(data: dict)
                       //will store in firstore/users/uid/docId/theUrl: the url
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. Yes the image file name was a typo. The issue I'm having is really uploading multiple images and then setting those image URLs within the data object. You can see above I need to set firstImage and secondImage in these calls to the relevant urls so that I can then access them later from the object. But I'm struggling to do this. Uploading one image is fine as I can do the downloadURL call and then set my object properties from there. But how can I set both image URLs from this call?

Comment: @DevB1 There's nothing in the question that attempts to write two images to storage - which is good because you can't do that anyway ;-) To store both URL's you simply do that with two calls. I would suggest writing the initial node using a generated documentId. Then call a function to store each image in storage and write the URL to that documentId, and then call it again to write secondImage to that same documentId. Something like *func uploadImage(withDocId: String, fieldName: String, theImage: UIImage)*. Pass the docId, the field to store it in (firstImage, secondImage etc) and the image.